# How should I write my this.props.function in Swipeout`s props onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

I know I can write a function in [Swipeout](https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout) like this

```
var swipeButton = [{
    text:'delete', 
    type:'delete',
    onPress: function(){ alert('button pressed') }
}]
```

But I have a function named `removeItem`, it gets a rowID from ListView. I think, maybe I can write in onPress like this:

```
onPress: () => this.props.removeItem(rowID)
```

The props `removeItem` has been transmitted to the component which includes the 'Swipeout' part. But it did not work, so I want to know how I should correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

When using arrow functions, the `this` keyword doesn't work like you'd expect from normal functions. It points to the context of the lexical scope. This should work:

```
onPress: function () { this.props.removeItem(rowID) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution, if I use `{ this.props.removeItem(rowID) }`, the red error message is "undefined is not an object", I think maybe I should write like`{ ()=>this.props.removeItem(rowID) }` for the function removeItem get a parameter "rowID", the compiling is ok, but click the Button, it has no answer, so I think it could be a syntax mistake for swipeout props "onPress", do you have any other ideas? Need any other details, let me   know, thx a lot :D